# long table to wide table in R

Tags: r

```
df = data.frame(record = c(20200525,20200608,20200608,20200615,20200615,20200622,20200622,20200701,20200701,20200706,20200706,20200713,20200713,20200727,20200727,20200803), team = c("A","A","B","B","C","C","D","D","E","E","F","F","G","G","H","H"))
```

Want to use df$record min as value of column S, max as value of column E in each team.
and would be looking for an answer like this:

[image]

I tried using:

```
df %>% mutate(S = top_n(1, record) ,E = top_n(-1, record))
```

and it gave me Error...
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution. Group by `team` and then summarise the data.

```r
df = data.frame(record = c(20200525,20200608,20200608,20200615,20200615,
                           20200622,20200622,20200701,20200701,20200706,
                           20200706,20200713,20200713,20200727,20200727,
                           20200803), 
                team = c("A","A","B","B","C","C","D","D","E",
                         "E","F","F","G","G","H","H"))

suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr))

df %>%
  group_by(team) %>%
  summarise(S = min(record), E = max(record))
#> # A tibble: 8 × 3
#>   team         S        E
#>   <chr>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 A     20200525 20200608
#> 2 B     20200608 20200615
#> 3 C     20200615 20200622
#> 4 D     20200622 20200701
#> 5 E     20200701 20200706
#> 6 F     20200706 20200713
#> 7 G     20200713 20200727
#> 8 H     20200727 20200803
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>